# link to id on page but reposition

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've used a modified themeforest template for a single php page and have an issue where the navigation links that take you to the various unique id's on the page are working fine but cut off the top part of the section h3 that it has linked to.
It's a positioning problem for sure and most likely to do with the modifications I made to the flex-slider that the template included.
But I can't determine how to adjust the css (or script) to correct the issue.

For example, the site is http://goudkamp.stacklaw.com.au/ and when you click Services, you can see what I mean.
I have the template on the site as well so you can see how it SHOULD work - http://goudkamp.stacklaw.com.au/v2/template/.

I came across another article that suggested using the script

```
if(window.location.hash.length){
     $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 100);
}
```

However, I don't think I should need it when the template works perfectly.
I just don't know where to start looking to make the necessary adjustments.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait - I found it!
After looking at the suggestion on the other article, it made me think that it must be done in the theme's custom scripts.  So I looked in the custom.js file for any script that referenced the main nav.

There was an "offset" line with the markup "//use this to position the window exactly where you want".  Testing a small change to this had the desired effect.

Thanks anyway.